# rviz not working for sicklms

Tags: ros, laser, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm able to connect to my sensor, i am also able to see the data using rostopic echo /scan, However rosrun rviz rviz gives me a blank map.
Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172696/rviz-not-working-for-sicklms/) by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-06-03**:
Did you add the laser topic in rviz? What frame is the laser scan in? What is your fixed_frame in rviz?

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-06-10**:
these are my settings

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9a6hcspwipq19q/rviz.jpg

the error under LaserScan Status is :- Transform [sender=/sicklms] For frame [laser]: Fixed Frame [base_laser] does not exist

i tried editing the fixed_frame as map , still didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a transform problem. The laser measurements are published in the base_laser coordinate frame, but rviz is trying to display them in the "laser" or "map" coordinate frame. Set your fixed frame to "base_laser" and you should see the data displayed. If you want to use another frame you need to make sure TF transforms are published to connect base_laser to your other frames (for instance by using http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher and a urdf)

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-06-10**:
my fixed fram is set to base_laser only, still no data. I do not understand what is supposed to be done. Sorry for being a noob but please help.

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-06-10**:
okay i just typed /laser in my global options-> fixed fram and it started working. Can you please tell me what was the mistake. Can you also tell me how do i manipulate the reading off the lms thanx (like how do i program it ?)

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-06-10**:
sounds like the laser is actually using the "laser" coordinate frame.... what do you see in the frame_id field of the laser message when you echo it?

**Comment by [Tchanam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21453/tchanam/) on 2015-01-22**:
Stuck at the same point.   Have tried changing the Fixed Frame under Global Options from "map"  to "base_laser" and  "laser".   I can see the data being published  when I do rostopic echo /scan.   Still no data showing up on map.

**Comment by [Tchanam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21453/tchanam/) on 2015-01-22**:
Got it to work.   Changed the Fixed Frame in Global Options to "laser"  and the topic in LaserScan to "/scan".